# Angular 2 and Bootstrap 3. Different integration approaches

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, single-page-application, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate `Bootstrap 3` into my `Angular 2` project.
I have two choices:

1. Use `npm install bootstrap --save` command and install Bootstrap 3
   to my project.
2. Install angular bootstrap using `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`,
   which is based on Angular and there won't be any jquery dependancies.

What is the main difference between these two approaches. Which one is better for single page applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngx-bootstrap` comes with pre-defined components out of the box which can be used directly in your angular app
while `bootstrap` is the pure library where you need to build the components by yourself

If you like re-inventing the wheel (aka being flexible and BYO) it is better to use bootstrap, but if you like pre-made components which are quite easy to use (still you can participate and create missing or custom components by yourself)

Hint: `ngx-bootstrap` for Bootstrap 4 is not feature complete yet, so there are couple of components missing. Not sure about Bootstrap 3 coverage. Still we have chosen to go with ngx-bootstrap as it saved us some time.

Comment: is it true, that if I want to use ngx-bootstrap components, I have to include basic bootstrap in my project first?

Answer (score 0):

In short both are good however

Having Angular and Bootstrap in a single project is very common and both serve different purpose. At the end of the day think about including js and css to help html and if you can manage these dependencies then that is cream on top. You can manage through npm, webpack or on your own.

Others can only tell you not to mix these things so you dont have to run npm install, gulp update-dependecies and then grunt resolve etc tasks just to make sure your dependency files are loaded. I would say carry on with any and enjoy development rather than worrying about such things.